# Parar una animacion CSS en cierto grado de rotacion

Tags: html, css3

Como puedo parar la animacion de rotacion al 90º por ejemplo? Sin que vuela a su estado inicial.

Mi idea es que del estado vertical gire al 60º, despues vuelva al 40º y despues al 60º. (como simulando la caida de un cartel de madera clavado a la pared)

Aca dejo el ejemplo con el gatito mal humorado.
http://jsfiddle.net/Ugc5g/9821/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esto es lo que tendrías que hacer para que la `img` obtenga la animación `60deg 40deg 60deg` que requieres (ya puedes jugar con los tiempos para adecuarla exactamente a lo que necesites):

```css
.image {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    margin:-60px 0 0 -60px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-animation: rotate 2s forwards;
    -moz-animation: rotate 2s forwards;
    -ms-animation: rotate 2s forwards;
    -o-animation: rotate 2s forwards;
    animation: rotate 2s forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
    0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    45% { -webkit-transform: rotate(60deg); }
    75% { -webkit-transform: rotate(40deg); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(60deg); }
}

@keyframes rotate {
    0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    45% { -webkit-transform: rotate(60deg); }
    75% { -webkit-transform: rotate(40deg); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(60deg); }
}
```

```html
<img class="image" src="http://makeameme.org/media/templates/120/grumpy_cat.jpg" alt="" width="120" height="120">
```

Espero que te sirva, saludos !

Comment: Muchas gracias Camilo!